# how to move some directory in github

Tags: git, github

I have linux local git. but I wish to use github at the same time

I read, https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/01/totw-copying-a-full-git-repo/

but It can't help me. because I want to move only some sub directories.

my plan is it.

```
local git ------> main working repos
/ lib
/ docs
/ src
/ img

github -----> only source repos
/ src
```

how to do?
the simplest way is change the origin far commit. but We can't. many users use my local git. they will only want to command "git commit" when work.

second way, I periodically delete unnecessary files and upload them to github.
but this way is become dirty log. or lost log. and, I wish to show only sub folder(src)'s log. no other log should come out.

thanks,

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question. I think you want to track different files in your local repository and your GitHub repository?

Comment: yes. but a few file is same.

Comment: This is technically possible using multiple branches, but it's awkward and you'll be fighting against the tools. A better solution would be to split your single repository into multiple repositories, or adjusting your point of view. What's your motivation for excluding `lib/`, `docs/`, and `img/` on GitHub?

Comment: It is an example. I want to publish some modules (a, b) in my github. and modules (c, d) that have not yet been developed to work in my local.
In other words, I want to publish some subfolders of the src folder.

Comment: I know simply way. it is hard copy.  but I wrote log hard. I want the way the logs are kept.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a `.gitignore` file in your root directory to exclude the other diretories:

```
lib
docs
img
```

Comment: I created .gitignore, but is not work after git merge.